# Map object if property is found in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my case.

```
data: [
    {
      q: "question 1",
      a: "answer 1"
    }, 
    {
      q: "question 2"
    }
]
```

How can I map this into `key: value` pair so that the final output is `{ "question 1": "answer 1"}`?

The trick is that only if `a` property exists then it should be assigned to the new object as above example `{ "question N": "answer N"}`.

I have tried combining `.map()` and `.filter()`, but it didn't work.

For example:

```
const obj = data.map(e => e.q).filter(s => s.a)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to filter element first and then map

```js
let data = [{q: "question 1",a: "answer 1"},{q: "question 2"}]

const obj = data.filter(s => s.a)
                .map(({q,a}) => ({ [q]: a }))

console.log(obj)
```

---

Can we get output as object, you can use reduce and build an Object,

```js
let data = [{q: "question 1",a: "answer 1"},{q: "question 2"}]

const obj = data.reduce((op,{q,a})=>{
  if( a ) op[q] = a
  return op
},{})

console.log(obj)
```

---

In modern browser you can `Object.fromEntries` too

```js
let data = [{q: "question 1",a: "answer 1"},{q: "question 2"}]

const obj = Object.fromEntries(data.filter(s => s.a)
                .map(({q,a}) => [q,a]))

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible that this is object, so: 
`{ "question 1": "answer 1" }`

Comment: @storagemode11 have a look at the second snippet

Comment: @CodeManiac, Looks great, thanks. What if `obj` has some data, so we don't want to reassign to it, but instead just to append data?

Comment: @storagemode11 you can merge two object. [`How to merge two objects in JS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically), and if obj is an array then you can simply concat values

Answer (score 4):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let data = [{ q: "question 1", a: "answer 1" }, { q: "question 2" } ];

let result = data.map(item => {
  if (item.q && item.a) {
    return {
      [item.q]: item.a
    };
  }
}).filter(item => item); // Filter undefined values.

console.log(result);
```

Comment: [Code Maniac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58612968/1218980) does this, but better. Filtering first reduces the complexity of the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible that this is object, so: 
`{ "question 1": "answer 1" }`

Comment: @storagemode11 - If you have multiple items in array, then you'll get multiple objects. If you want to access just the first object you can do it as `result[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

For a single object, you could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) for creating a sigle object out of key/value pairs.

```js
var data = [{ q: "question 1", a: "answer 1" }, { q: "question 2" }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data
        .map(({ q, a }) => [q, a])
        .filter(([_, a]) => a)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the reduce method effectively ensure u run a single loop with a conditional inside, instead of a map and a filter like the previous answers which are both definitely correct as well

```
let data = [{q: "question 1",a: "answer 1"},{q: "question 2"}]

const obj = data.reduce((acc,cur) => {
If(cur.a && cur.q) {
acc.push({[`${cur.q}`]: cur.a})
}. 
return acc
} ,[])

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks Emile. Typed the answer from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I believe you're trying to do, and this will account for multiple questions as well.

First, you need to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get rid of anything that doesn't have the `a` property defined.

Then, you can use a [`reducer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

This reducer **acc**umulates a brand new object (starting with `{}` which is passed as the 2nd argument to `reduce`). It assigns each property (question name) to each value (answer) and returns the new accumulated variable, until it's done iterating.

```js
const data = [{q: "question 1", a: "answer 1"}, {q: "question 2"}, {q: "question 3", a: "answer 3"}]

const obj = data.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('a'))
    .reduce(function(acc, cur) {
        acc[cur.q] = cur.a
        return acc 
    }, {})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
const obj = data.filter(s => s.a).map(e => ({[e.q]: e.a}))
```

Comment: Why does one get downvoted for that, this is a perfectly correct answer and even more compact than most of the other ones. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this is not having any difference with my answer, except some spacing removed. also code only answers are not considered as good practice on so

Comment: It's the same thing as the top answer, but on oneline... It brings nothing new here. Code without explanation is another reason for a downvote.

Comment: Why does similarity to the top answer make this one bad? Automatically assuming I stole the top answer's code? Original solutions often look similar for simple problems like this one.
Talking about explanations, I suspected OP had the required background knowledge, though I kinda see your point.

Comment: @onetyone I have not downvoted this either, but the problem is probably just with simply giving an answer without teaching anything. For the most part I don't think question askers are seeking merely solutions, but knowledge in general. Like, a great answer would not just give a solution, but would explain what the solution does, why the answerer has chosen such a methodology, and would perhaps directly quote and/or link to any applicable documentation, etc.

Comment: You probably already knew everything I just said. I'm not trying to be condescending and hope I didn't come across as such.

Comment: _"I don't think question askers are seeking merely solutions"_ It's not just about the asker, it's about the quality of the content as a whole. Since an answer like this brings nothing to the thread, even if it works, it won't be well received by the community.